# How to Direct the Cmd line output to jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

```
Stage("execution") {
    Steps {
       bat 'start cmd.exe /c c:\\users\\doc\\sample.bat'
    }
}
```

The above script is just opening the `cmd` prompt and executing it. It's not taking the output of the execution. Even if the execution fails, the stage is shown as successful and it moves to the next stage for deployment. I want to develop it so that the output in the `cmd` prompt should be taken as input by Jenkins and stage should go on. If the stage fails during execution, the stage should show failure and if the execution succeeds, the stage should show success in Jenkins. Can anyone help?

Another question: If the batch file is located in Git, how to give the path in the above script?

Comment: What do you mean by not taking output of the execution?

Comment: As the output executed in the cmd prompt the jenkins was not able to read it we need to do some changes in the output then it will read .

Answer (score 1):

Using the `start` command, you are creating a new detached console process which Jenkins cannot keep track of.

Do it like this instead:

```
bat 'call "c:\\users\\doc\\sample.bat"'
```

This runs the batch file in the same environment as the current script and waits for the batch file to end. Jenkins will be able to capture the standard output and detect errors through the exit code of the batch file.

You may write `@call` to hide the command-line from the output.

Comment: Actually I need to pass some dynamic parameters while executing so I called cmd.exe so that I can pass parameters in the script ..I know that we can pass parameters in jenkins by using build with parameters. But my plan of automation is once developer push the code to git then the pipeline will start which deploy the code from dev to test environment and execute there if it is successful then deploy to UAT env . So developer can't come to jenkins and give parameters so if window pops up on his screen he can give .so I want jenkins to capture the output in cmd line.

Comment: @anandchinnu I don't understand. Do you want a developer to input something during the build? For that you can use the [`input`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step) step.

Comment: Actually the script is parameterized. We need to give some inputs for the script to execute. So when I run the above pipeline it is opening the windows command line to execute the script but its not waiting for the inputs it's closes in 15 sec and the execution fails as I didn't pass the parameters but the stage is will successful as it is not taking the output of windows cmd line. So I need to do some changes in the pipeline so that the output of windows cmd line should be captured by jenkins.