# How do I make jenkins to capture the output of external source like windows command line

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops, jenkins-groovy, devops-services

Stage("execution"){
Steps{bat 'start cmd.exe /c c:\users\doc\sample.bat'}}

The above script is just opening the windows cmd prompt and executing it . it's not taking the output of the execution . And my script is parameterized but it is not even waiting for me 
to pass some dynamic values.Even if the execution is failed the stage is showing as successful and passing to next stage like deploying ....so I want to develop it so that the output in the windows cmd prompt should take as input by jenkins and based on that the next stage should go on ...if it fails in cmd prompt the stage in jenkins should also fail ...if the execution is successful in cmd prompt the stage should be successful in Jenkins....can anyone help ?

Comment: Why are you posting the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61287022/how-to-direct-the-cmd-line-output-to-jenkins) again?

Comment: If you want to provide additional details, please edit the existing question.